# Putting brackets around a specific column

Tags: python, bash, sed

With a bash script, I extracted a .conllu file into a three columned .txt with the Lemma, POS and meaning. So some kind of dictionary. Now I am trying to make it prettier by putting the second column (POS) in brackets.

It looks like:

```
ami NOUN    mother
amo VERB    sleep
asima   NOUN    younger_sister
ati NOUN    older_sister
```

Every column is seperated by a tab.

I want it to look like this:

```
ami (NOUN)  mother
amo (VERB)  sleep
asima   (NOUN)  younger_sister
ati (NOUN)  older_sister
```

and ideally:

```
ami (NOUN)  - mother
amo (VERB)  - sleep
asima   (NOUN)  - younger_sister
ati (NOUN)  - older_sister
```

I tried regex and sed

```
sed -e 's/[a-zA-Z]+ /(/g' -e 's+[a-zA-Z]+=[a-zA-Z]+/)/g' dictjaa.txt > test.txt
```

but failed unfortunately.

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried that failed?

Comment: sed -e 's/[a-zA-Z]+ /(/g' -e 's+[a-zA-Z]+=[a-zA-Z]+/)/g' dictjaa.txt > test.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
sed -E 's/([^[:alpha:]]+)([^ ]*)  /\1(\2) -/' input_file
ami (NOUN) -  mother
amo (VERB) -  sleep
asima   (NOUN) -  younger_sister
ati (NOUN) -  older_sister
```

Comment: unfortunately i get the same output as my input..

Comment: it's tab separated. And I still get the same output..

Comment: @DIC `sed -E 's/^([[:alpha:]]+[^[:alpha:]]+)([^\t]*)\t/\1(\2) - /'`

Answer (score 1):

If there are always uppercase characters A-Z:

```
sed -E 's/([[:blank:]])([A-Z]+)[[:blank:]]+/\1(\2)  - /' dictjaa.txt > test.txt
```

The pattern matches:

- `([[:blank:]])` Capture group 1, match either a space or tab
- `([A-Z+])` Capture group 2, match 1+ uppercase chars A-Z
- `[[:blank:]]+` Match 1+ occurrences of either a space or tab

The content of *test.txt*:

```
ami (NOUN)  - mother
amo (VERB)  - sleep
asima   (NOUN)  - younger_sister
ati (NOUN)  - older_sister
```